# Parsley js Ajax validation

Tags: parsley.js

I have the following input field:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="username" 
    data-parsley-required 
    data-parsley-remote-validator="default"  
    data-parsley-remote-options='{ 
        "type": "POST",
        "url": "/User/user_exists", 
        "dataType": 
        "json", 
        "data": { "request": "ajax" } 
    }'
>
```

Now when the value of this input field changes, I wish to call the address `/User/user_exists` with the input's value + a checker value called: `request:"ajax"`

However when the value changes nothing happens.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

The rest of Parsley is enabled. I know this because the `data-required` field is being triggered.

Comment: Stupid question, but you *are* using `parsley.remote.js`, aren't you? http://parsleyjs.org/doc/download.html (Also, to validate on change, you need to declare `data-parsley-trigger="change"`.)

Comment: @Tomalak yes i am using parsley.remote.js :)